# How to join tables correctly. 0 rows returned is not correct

Tags: mysql, sql

Everything looks in order for the code to run, but the code isn't showing any rows. So, i must be doing something wrong. I can't figure out where the problem is.  The problem from my instructor is:

Use the AP database

Vendor name from the vendor table

Vendor Contact First Name and Vendor Contact Last Name from the vendor table but I need them concatenated together with a space between the names

Invoice Date from the invoice table

Only the day of from the Invoice Date

Invoice Number from the invoice table

The third and fourth characters from the Invoice Number

Line Item Amount from the invoice line items table

Calculate the commission which is the Line Item Amount * 15% and make it ONLY two decimals

The FROM is the Vendors table do JOINS on the others

The WHERE is where the Line Item Amount is greater than $2000 and the Invoice Date is between July 1, 2014 and July 31st, 2014 and I only want the ones that have either a 9 or a 2 in the Invoice Number

Sort by Invoice Date

// This is the only information he's given me for this assignment. ^

I've tried to join different columns together in different orders/joining tables in different orders.

```
select vendor_name as vendor, concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as Contact, 
DAY(invoice_date) as ofday, invoice_date,
SUBSTRING(invoice_number, 3,2) as thirdFourth, 
line_item_amount,round(line_item_amount*.15, 2) as Commission
from vendors v
JOIN vendor_contacts vc
ON v.vendor_id = vc.vendor_id
JOIN INVOICES INV
ON VC.VENDOR_ID = INV.VENDOR_ID
JOIN invoice_line_items ILI
ON INV.invoice_id = ILI.invoice_id
where line_item_amount > 2000
and invoice_date between '2014-7-1' and '2014-7-31'
and (invoice_number =9 OR invoice_number =2)
```

expected results : 
https://imgur.com/E81ix3o

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you put that query in a code block and do some spacing? That is incredibly difficult to read. EDIT: refreshed page and see that you have done that now.

Comment: You should not paste links to images, it's really hard to help you that way. In the image you posted I don't see invoice_number... maybe that's why this is not working...

Comment: You should format your dates like `'2014-07-01'` instead of `'2014-7-1'`

Comment: the invoice_number is the invoice column - his substring references it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are asking specifically for invoice_number 9 or 2. You don't have an invoice_number of 9 or 2 If you want invoice_numbers with 9 or 2 in you will need

```
invoice_number like '%9%' or invoice_number like '%2%'
```